# Why can't we embed an n-dimensional manifold in a n+1 dimensional Euclidean space? (isometrically?)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I've seen stuff like Whitney's embedding theorem and Nash embedding theorem (I don't actually understand their mathematical statement yet) from what I've seen those theorems say you can only embed a n-dimensional manifold in a 2n dimensional euclidean space, maybe 2n - 1 if you're lucky. But you can embed $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you can embed $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can embed any 2D manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so why doesn't it generalize to arbitrary dimensions? does that only work with $S^n$? do non-constant curvature manifolds just have too much information like different types of curvature and stuff so that it can't just be embedded into a Euclidean space who's dimension is just 1 higher than the manifold's dimension?

Why can't we isometrically embed an n-dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

I'm assuming I need a "isometric embedding" here, I think that means the embedding preserves distances.

my background: I only know linear algebra and multivariable calculus (and some very basic topology) and I haven't actually studied differential geometry and differential topology yet

Comment: Not that it necessarily answers your question but it isn't true that you can embed all 2D manifolds in $\Bbb{R}^3$. In particular the Klein bottle and $\Bbb{RP}^2$ cannot be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$. (They can be locally embedded but that is a different question.)

Comment: "Why can't it be done?" Because there are examples that demonstrate that it is impossible, as evidenced by the above comment. I don't think one should expect a deeper answer, whatever that may mean. (Although a general way to calculate a lower bound for embedding dimension, and showing somewhat generally that this bound must some times be larger than $n+1$ would be cool.)

Comment: Heuristically, your geometric structure has much more freedom in higher dimensions, so a priori more structures should be possible in higher dimensions. In this sense, it is (at least a priori) rather surprising that these embedding theorems exist and less surprising that you cannot always embed in the next dimension.

Comment: IIRC, a flat torus does not isometrically embed in Euclidean three-space, either.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang It was proven to be possible over half a century ago by Nash, and for the first time [visualized](https://youtu.be/RYH_KXhF1SY) in 2012.

Comment: To clarify regarding the flat torus, there is no $C^3$ isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there is a $C^1$ isometric embedding.  I forget what happens for $C^2$.

Comment: @Arthur You're right: I assumed _smooth_ was intended, though on closer reading OP did not specify.

Comment: Before I attempt my own answer, I want to know whether you know the definitions of a manifold and a Riemannian manifold. I ask this, because you say you haven't actually studied differential geometry and differential topology yet.

Comment: @Fishbane Ah right the klein bottle is a counterexample, thank you, so is it safe to say that every constant curvature n-dimensional manifold can be embedded in n+1 dimensiona Euclidean space?

Comment: @Arthur Yes there are examples, but there must be at least an intuitive reason why it can't be done, if there isn't a mathematical proof

Comment: @Deane Yes I do know the definition of a manifold, it's a topological space that may have whatever global structure but locally it "looks" like Euclidean space, more technically the neighborhood around every point is homeomorphic to a open subset of Euclidean space of suitable dimension (R^n if it's a n-dimensional manifold), and a Riemannian manifold is a differentiable manifold that has a metric tensor (technically a metric tensor field over the entire manifold) I haven't actually studied differential geometry but I have read about it a bit and asked grad students stuff about it

Comment: @QiZhu That's what I was thinking, it has more freedom to "exist" in different directions so you'd need a higher dimension (more directions) to properly embed it

Comment: @mastershooter77 No, there really mustn't be an intuitive reason. As I said, it would be cool, but it truly isn't something one should expect when on encounters an untrue statement.

Comment: @Arthur Imo one should always look for an intuitive reason.

Comment: @QiZhu It's a fine goal and ideal. As I have repeatedly said, it is cool if there is one. But it should not be expected. In addition, it's often unclear what "A reason that this statement is untrue" actually means, exactly how a concrete counterexample is not such a reason, and what kind of answer is actually good enough. That really varies from person to person, and it's nearly impossible for you to know (without mind reading) whether the answer you are thinking about (in this particular case or any other similar case) is good enough for the person asking the question.

Comment: @mastershooter77 Honestly I couldn't tell you that. For starters I don't really study much differtiable topology so I don't encounter curvature much, I have mostly done algebraic topology. However a bigger issue I see is that in higher dimensions curvature stops being a scalar so it isn't clear necessarily what you want when you say constant curvature. I'm sure one of the others can do a better job answering that if you want.

Comment: @mastershooter77 Additionally it is worth noting that curvature is not a topological invariant, but instead (I believe by the theorema egregium) a metric invariant. So it doesn't make sense to talk about the curvature of a Torus because the 'normal' Torus has non-zero curvature in some places but I believe that essentially by definition the flat Torus has zero curvature everywhere. As the names suggest these two spaces are topologically equivalent (homeomorphic) but have very different metric properties. Not that this is necessary overly relavent to embedding.

Comment: @mastershooter77 actually having thought about it the Klein bottle is once again a counter example because you can construct the flat Klein bottle which has zero curvature. As it is a Klein bottle it still can't be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$ but it also has constant curvature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your question somewhat unclear. Perhaps you are asking two separate questions?

The first question is a purely topological one. Can a manifold be embedded into Euclidean space as a hypersurface? Here, there is no notion of distance, and you're allowed to stretch or twist the manifold as much as you want. The Whitney embedding theorem says you can embed an $n$-manifold into Euclidean $2n$-space, but you're asking for something better.

Even this question is vague. Do you want to restrict to closed (compact) manifolds? Based on the examples you cite, it appears so. Do you want to restrict to orientable manifolds? That's a reasonable assumption, since a closed non-orientable manifold, such as the Klein bottle or real projective space, can never be embedded as a hypersurface. Do you want to restrict to smooth embeddings? I suggest that we do, since the situation becomes a lot more subtle yet complicated if you assume less. At that point, your question is a reasonable one, and indeed not so easy to come up with counterexamples. One simple reason is that it requires a topologically nontrivial example that has dimension 3 or more. I'm pretty sure that the complex projective plane (which is 4-dimensional) cannot be embedded into Euclidean 5-space. I'll let others cite other counterexamples and explain why.

Your second question appears to be: Given a Riemannian manifold, can it be embedded isometrically as a hypersurface in Euclidean space? Here, there is a well-defined distance function between two points, both on the Riemannian manifold and in Euclidean space. Isometric means that, given any two points on the hypersurface, the two distance functions agree. Here, there are two major theorems. Nash proved that any closed Riemannian manifold can be embedded smoothly and isometrically into Euclidean space of sufficiently high dimension. On the other hand, Nash and Kuiper proved that if a Riemannian manifold can be embedded as a hypersurface (this is the topological assumption discussed above), then there is a $C^1$ isometric embedding. Not only that, you can do this so that the hypersurface lies inside a ball of arbitrarily small radius. For example, you can embed both the standard unit sphere as well as the flat torus isometrically (distance preserving) into a ball of radius 1/10. This is amazing and obviously means the embedding is very wrinkly. You can see beautiful examples of this [here](http://hevea-project.fr).

Notice that since you can't differentiate a $C^1$ embedding map twice, there is no reasonable notion of curvature for such an embedding. So we usually assume at least $C^2$. Once you can define curvature, things get much more restrictive. In particular, it's easy to prove that any isometrically embedded closed hypersurface must have at least one point with positive curvature. This is easy to see intuitively. Just find the smallest sphere that contains the hypersurface. It has to touch the hypersurface somewhere, and at that point the hypersurface has to be more positively curved than the sphere. So a closed Riemannian manifold with negative curvature cannot be embedded smoothly and isometrically as a hypersurface, even if it can be embedded topologically (i.e., without preserving the distance function). The simplest examples are [surfaces with genus greater than 1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) These all have Riemannian metrics with negative curvature. With such a metric, they cannot be embedded smoothly isometrically as surfaces in Euclidean space (but can be embedded as $C^1$ isometric maps).

Some quick comments about constant curvature: Any closed orientable 2-manifold has a Riemannian metric with constant curvature, which is positive for a sphere, zero for a torus, and negative for a surface of genus greater than 1. There is a way to define [constant curvature for higher dimensional manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_curvature). There is a similar story as for surfaces.

A lot more can be said about both questions, but I'll stop here. You'll have plenty of time going forward to learn more.